# TestNG Overriding Report Generation

Tags: java, testng

At the end of the TestNG run, we have a couple things that I am noticing are happening.

We get the following message displayed on the console (this example shown with failing tests):

```
    53 tests completed, 6 failed, 1 skipped
There were failing tests. See the results at: file:///Users/***/Workspace/***/build/test-results/
```

And, of course an HTML report is generated. What I would like to do, is to add a step to this process where we are copying the generated HTML reports to a different server on the same network, and also publishing a notification in Slack. I think the slack part is pretty easy, just sending in a HTTP request with a json body, but where would I put the code to do this? Can I even do this without having to recompile TestNG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to implement your own reporter: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-reporters

Answer (score 0):

Dont understand your question completely .

> " but where would I put the code to do this?"

At the end i suppose. You can implement your Listener and then in `onFinish` method you can implement the copying part.

Or

you can do the copying at the end after testng run is complete. How are you running testng tests ? That will be important in that case.